# How can I know the number of views for a feed element?

Tags: chatter

We are trying to count the times a feed element has been read since the last Salesforce1 v.14 app now shows this value per each feed.

When calling the feed-elements, under capabilities, we always get:

```
"readBy": {
    "isReadByMe": true,
    "lastReadDateByMe": "yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.000Z",
    "page": null
}
```

page is always null.

We were also considering using the `Interactions` feed element field but following the documentation:

> The number of individual views, likes, and comments on a feed post.

So this does not sound correct either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of factors that determine whether the page info is getting returned in the "readyBy" capabilities. One being that the feed element has to belong to either a Private or Unlisted Group. The other factor is the context user has to be either a member of the group or has View All Data permission.

You can read more about it here:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=collab_group_seenby.htm&type=0

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However SF1 seems to be using interactions for this which we found has an issue in that if a user likes, comments and views in detail, it counts as 3 Views. This is not optimal, and we're wondering if there's a workaround or alternative solution so that in this scenario it counts as 1 View?

Comment: I don't believe so. SF1 only supports interactions and not the readby. For interactions, each one of those actions is considered an interaction. Therefore, the count there becomes 3.